# Render controller layouts ($this->layout) from a helper class/function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a service that loads content in two ways:

1. Via standard http requests
2. Via ajax requests

I do this by checking the request in each controller method, like this:

```
public function showIndex() {
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        // return ajax version of index
    }
   $this->layout->body = View::make('index');
}
```

The problem is that i have to do this in each controller method, which means a lot of duplicated code.

So, i would like to create a function somewhere that can handle all of this. I'm assuming it would look something like this:

```
public static function load($route, $data)
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
    // return ajax version of index
    }
    $this->layout->body = View::make($route)->with($data);
}
```

and then use

```
Class::load('index', $data);
```

to load the content.

But where should i put this class? I need to have access to $this so i can render the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use your own controllers?

You can create a BaseController and extend all your controllers from it:

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function render($view, array $data = []) 
    {
        $this->layout->body = View::make($view)->with($data);
    }

}

class PostController extends BaseController {

    public function showIndex() 
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            // return ajax version of index
        }

        $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

And you could even put your ajax rendering system there, uncluttering completely your controller methods:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function render($view, array $data = []) 
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::json($data);
        }

        $this->layout->body = View::make($view)->with($data);
    }

}

class PostController extends BaseController {

    public function showPost($postData) 
    {
        return $this->render('post', $postData);
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel stupid now :) Thanks a lot! This is exactly how i wanted it.